# Удалить элемент из датафрейма

Tags: python, python-2.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть два датафрейма `trans_train_data` и `train_labels`. `train_labels` содержит метки классов: 0,1,-1. Нужно удалить все -1 из `train_labels` и соответствующие строки в `trans_train_data`. То есть если в train_labels -1 стоит на 3,45 и 78 позиции, то в `trans_train_data` нужно удалить строки  3,45 и 78. Индексы в данных датафреймах произвольные (то есть не 0,1,2,3... а 98, 45623, 3,64785...)

Пробовала задать новые индексы через `.reindex()`, но в этом случае появляются NaN и меняется порядок следования элементов.

Так же пробовала через генератор:

```
generator = enumarate(train_labels)
out = [x: for i,x in generator if x==-1]
```

Возвращает массив с неправильными индексами. 
Подскажите что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

Исходные DataFrame's:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10,3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   a  b  c
0  2  7  6
1  8  8  0
2  7  7  8
3  9  5  1
4  5  0  9
5  1  8  4
6  9  1  5
7  8  3  3
8  1  0  7
9  2  3  7

In [3]: train_labels = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([-1,0,1], 10), columns=['val'])

In [4]: train_labels
Out[4]:
   val
0    1
1    1
2    0
3   -1
4   -1
5    1
6   -1
7   -1
8    1
9    1
```

нахождение нужных элементов индекса:

```
In [5]: np.where(train_labels.val==-1)[0]
Out[5]: array([3, 4, 6, 7], dtype=int64)
```

фильтрование:

```
In [6]: df.loc[np.where(train_labels.val==-1)[0]]
Out[6]:
   a  b  c
3  9  5  1
4  5  0  9
6  9  1  5
7  8  3  3
```

удаление соотв. строк:

```
In [10]: df = df.drop(np.where(train_labels.val==-1)[0])

In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   a  b  c
0  2  7  6
1  8  8  0
2  7  7  8
5  1  8  4
8  1  0  7
9  2  3  7
```

или еще проще:

```
In [15]: df.loc[train_labels.val!=-1]
Out[15]:
   a  b  c
0  2  7  6
1  8  8  0
2  7  7  8
5  1  8  4
8  1  0  7
9  2  3  7
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все так просто решается, а я начинаю изобретать велосипед(